# Should I use MonoDroid or Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am having a very hard time deciding if I should make this application in android or monodroid.

I simply just don't know enough about either to make an informed decision. So hopefully a person who has more experience with both of these can help me out.

I am a .net developer(mostly asp.net mvc). So I work with visual studios 2010 and .net all the time. I have not done java or used eclipse since my Java 101 class many years ago.

So in this case monodroid seems like the clear winner as I can utilize that experience.

The application I am planning to make will also be eventually ported to the iphone so the thought here is if I need to make something say with google maps / GPS, I can extract the common code out and reuse it.

However I don't know how much common code there will be because I don't know how much android specific stuff would be needed. It could end up that to do maps in iphone and android even with mono there could be zero res-useable code.

Finally the biggest downside I can see is plugins. For instance I need to use a swipe view layout where a user can go from one view to another with a flick. This to my knowledge does not exist in native android.

I know there are plugins but of course they are all java and to my knowledge it can be a pain to get these to work in mono-droid.

So I am not sure if I am going to suffer at this end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am a .net developer(mostly asp.net mvc). So I work with visual
>   studios 2010 and .net all the time. I have not done java or used
>   eclipse since my Java 101 class many years ago.
>
> So in this case monodroid seems like the clear winner as I can utilize
>   that experience.

You're right, it sounds to me like monodroid is the way to go.

> Finally the biggest downside I can see is plugins. For instance I need
>   to use a swipe view layout where a user can go from one view to
>   another with a flick. This to my knowledge does not exist in native
>   android.

You can implement this in Android, it just requires some smart programming. For example, you can sense swipe touch events, and you can then handle them by launching a new Activity.

Comment: do you have anything to off by to get me started.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `do you have anything to off by`. Can you expand on this?

Comment: @Phil- Sorry do you have an examples of setting up swipe touch events in monodroid? Like what are the event names I have to listen for and etc.

Comment: @chobo2, I have never used monodroid. You said that three was no `swipe view` available in *native* Android. So, if you were using Android (not Monodroid), you could override `onTouch(...)` in your main `Activity`, or if you create a custom `View`, you can override onMotionEvent, and handle swipes this way (by calculating the distance between down and up presses). You can use `Intent` to launch a new `Activity`.

Comment: @ Phil - Well if you know if there is a swipe view let me know :) . I am trying to get gestures to work in monodroid but so far no luck as there is on fling that might help.

Comment: @Phil: Mono for Android attempts to expose the ~same Android API that Java provides, allowing use by managed code (modulo a few changes, e.g. get/set methods to properties, setOnFooListener methods to Foo events, migration of integral constants to enumerations, etc.). Thus, if you'd override View.onMotionEvent() in Java, you would override View.OnMotionEvent() in Mono for Android: http://docs.mono-android.net/Android.Views.View.OnTouchEvent%20(Android.Views.MotionEvent)

Comment: Moreover, if you need to write the application for iOS you can use MonoTouch as well. Using conditional compilation directives separating Monodroid from Monotouch code, with any luck, you'll be able to share a good amount of code.